# shared_ptr of a template class using gcc 4.6

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Trying to achieve following in c++11

```
template< class A >
    class B{
         std::shared_ptr< A > a_shared_ptr;
    };

B< int > b;
```

Is it possible?

Getting following error

../../src/threading/node.h:26: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘shared_ptr’ with no type
../../src/threading/node.h:26: error: invalid use of ‘::’
../../src/threading/node.h:26: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token

Comment: Of course, why shouldn't it be possible?

Comment: Did you try *compiling* it? (after adding the semi-colon at the end of B's closing curly)?

Comment: In C11? No, definitely not. It doesn't have templates nor classes.

Comment: Sure you added `#include <memory>` to your header?

Comment: Edited the question with compiling errors I got.

Comment: http://ideone.com/pHm85B either you have another code or you are using compiler without c++11 support enabled.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes this is possible.**

As [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) is a new C++11 feature, you have to enable the C++11 support on you compiler. Under GCC, the option are : `-std=c++0x` or `-std=gnu++0x`.

If I do not enable those features I get exactly the same errors as you.

The other point is : Do not forget to include the header for `std::shared_ptr` :

```
#include <memory>
```

Answer (score 5):

Just include header for std::shared_ptr, it does compiles fine:

```
#include <memory>

template< class A >
class B{
    std::shared_ptr< A > a_shared_ptr;
};

int main()
{
    B< int > b;
    return 0;
}
```